# Cancelation Property of Groups: $a^i = a^j \implies a^{j-i} = e$ where $j - 1 \geq 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Say we have a group $G$ and a finite nonempty subgroup $H$ of $n$ elements. We want to prove that $H$ has in inverse for of its elements. If $a = e$ then by definition of the inverse of $e$ as $e$ we have $a^{-1} = e$. Now suppose we build a product of $n+1$ elements

$$a^1 \cdot a^2 \cdot ... \cdot a^{n+1}$$

Now there must be two factors in this product that are equal to each other, as we have $n+1$ factors but only $n$ distinct elements in the group.

$$a^i = a^j \text{ where } 1 \leq i < j \leq n + 1$$

Then by the cancelation property in groups we have $a^{j-i} =e$.

Why is that? I don't see where the cancelation property ($ab = ac \iff b = c$ and $ba = ca \iff b = c$) plays into this. Can somebody elaborate on this and show some more steps in this deduction?

Actually, how do we even know what $a^{j-i}$ means? I know what $a^ja^i$ means. I also know what $(a^j)^{-1}$ means, but I do not know what $a^{-j}$ means, unless by convention $a^{-j} \equiv (a^j)^{-1}$?

## edit

screen capture of the proof:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKuyz.png

Comment: Is a an arbitrary element? (I haven't worked much with groups... also, is  $a^n$ defined as $a \cdot a \cdot ... \cdot a$, with n a's? If so, it seems that $a^{j-i}$ would be taking the "product" of a with itself j-i times)

Comment: I think $a^n$ is not $n$ factors of $a$ but merely some element identified by $n$. Probably $a_n$ would have been less confusing, but $a^n$ is the way it is written in my book.

Comment: It seems that they do use the "multiply a by itself n times" definition (at the very least, it's the simplest explanation I can think of for why they say $aa^{j-i-1}=a^{j-i}$).

Comment: from $a^{j-i-1}=aa^{j-i}$ we can assume that $a^ba=a^{b+1}$, so $a^n$ is probably define as product(or at least by some action that hold $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$)

Comment: Okay, this way it makes sense. I did not feel confident just assuming this. But if you don't see a more generic way in which this makes sense, then probably this is what is meant.

Comment: @user3578468 it is okay not to feel comfortable, unless your book define $a^n$ then this assumption is really not something we can say for every group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be completely misunderstanding this (please let me know if so! My entire experience with groups amounts to peeking at their definitions).

If you have $a^i=a^j$, then $a^{j-i}a^{j}=a^{j-i}a^i=a^{j-i+i}=a^j=ea^j$.Since you have $a^{j-i}a^j=ea^j$, the 2nd cancellation property gives $a^{j-i}=e$.

Comment: Does this necessarily assume that $a^n = \underbrace{a \cdot \dots \cdot a}_{n}$?

Comment: why does $a^ia^j=a^{i+j}$, you need to be sure how he define $a^n$ to be able to say so

Comment: Yep. So this answer may or may not be dubious, depending on how the "powers" are defined (it does appear to be how the Wikipedia page on groups defines it, though).

Comment: @user3578468 we dont know how he define $a^n$ so we cant assume that yet

Comment: I guess that is where my problem comes from, it is not clear how the product is defined for $G$ in the book. I will edit my question with a screen capture of it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as a notation we show the product $\underbrace{a \cdot \dots \cdot a}_{n}$ as $a^n$.

Secondly,

$$a^j = a^i \Rightarrow a^j * e = a^i *e \Rightarrow a^i * a^{j-i} * e = a^i *e$$ and by the **cancellation property** we can cancel $a^i$ in both sides, hence
$$a^{j-i} = e$$